# What is the mathematical principle of buddy algorithm?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management

The buddy algorithm is:

> The buddy for any block of size $2^k$ is another block of the same size, and with the same page frame number except that the `kth` bit is reversed.

Example:

If the block size if $2^3$ and the start page frame number(aka `pfn`) of this block is `0xC`, the page frame number of the buddy of this block is `pfn=0x4`.

This algorithm is very ingenious but I have two questions.

1. Why the buddy of `0xC` is `0x4` instead of `0x14`?
2. Why reversing the `kth` bit does the trick?

References:
http://research.cs.vt.edu/AVresearch/MMtutorial/buddy.php

Comment: I think that your example is incorrect - starting point of block with size 2^n should be aligned to 2^n. Then, reversing the n'th bit of that address, you will find its buddy, and together they form block of size 2^(n+1)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation

Answer (score 1):

The buddy algorithm is just treating your memory of size $2^K$ as a binary tree where the root is the entire memory, and each node of size $2^k$ has two children which are the two equal size subblocks of size $2^{k-1}$.

The buddy system restricts you to only splitting a node into its two children (which are then the two buddies), or taking two buddies and coalescing them into their parent.  This restriction is put in place entirely to enable the cute/ingenious trick of identifying your buddy by flipping the $k$th bit.

Other than being cute, there is very little to recommend buddy systems as memory allocators.  More general systems that allow you to coalesce with any neighbor, even if it's not your buddy, are slightly more expensive to compute per deallocation, but result in much less internal and external  fragmentation in practice.